# SQL Server 2008 not showing the Management Studio option

Tags: sql-server-2008

I know this question is asked for many times.But I am unable to find a solution after googling much.I have installed **MSSQL SERVER 2008(64 bit).(Windows 7 OS)** in my system.I'm trying to create a new database using SQL Server 2008, and these are the steps that I follow:

Start -> Microsoft SQL Server 2008 ->

I get 2 options:

```
 Configuration tools
 Import and Export Data (32 bit).
```

When I choose `Configuration tools` and then get these options:

```
 SQL Server Configuration Manager
 SQL Server error and usage reporting
 SQL Server Installation Center
```

When I click `1. SQL Server Configuration Manager` it shows `sqlserverservices` with status running.Unfortunately I didn't find `SQLServer Management Studio` inside this.When I searched this in the search bar I found it under the `Documents` and when I clicked,it shows 4 folders named

- Code Snippets
- Projects
- Settings
- Templates

I am unable to create database.Guys please help me

[image: Screen shot when I click server management studio]

[image: search]

Comment: Should be another Microsoft SQL Server folder with SSMS inside. Mine's called Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: Did you check the SSMS.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\ location

Comment: @Knightwisp Since I am newbie,I dont get you about SSMS.Mine is MS SQL SERVER 2008 EXPRESS.Is it differenet from what you mention in your comment

Comment: @AnazA SQL Server Management Studio - what you're looking for.

Comment: @Knightwisp I cant create database after clicking management studio.It shows only 4 folders as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Oasis I didnt find SSMS.exe inside the location folder.It contains only 3 files

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you have not selected the Management Tools Options while installing the sql server.Check all client tools options with Management Tools option while installing.

Try to reinstall or repair your installation.

After completed your installation Press Windows+R and type SSMS then Press Enter.It will open SQL Server Management studio.

Comment: I have selected all options including Client tools during installation

Comment: @AnazA : Then you should see ssms.exe in SSMS.exe in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\ location

Comment: ssms.exe is not found.What to do then @Oasis

Comment: Then there is some problem in your installation.Try to repair or reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you haven't installed Sql Server Management Studio, only Sql Server.
Look for Sql Server Management Studio in the start menu and if it's not there then you'll need to install it.

Image:
[image]

Comment: SQL Server Management studio is shown in the start menu.But when I click it,it shows 4 folders as I mentioned in the question

Comment: Do you mean 4 folders in the Object Explorer of ssms?

Comment: Ya..they are:Code Snippets,
Projects,
Settings,
Templates

Comment: Can you post screenshots of where you try to open ssms?

Comment: @Mitco I have placed screen shots

Comment: I added an image of my start menu, let me know if you have the same option, if I understood your question.

Comment: @Mitco For me When I search like "management studio",it is coming like this,but in the form of a folder.I have placed the screen shot

Comment: Then you're missing something, try and install this: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7593